# Jquery adding an array to the end of an array without merging with existing items

Tags: jquery

Alo,

I am trying to create a dynamic array for Jqplot and running a problem. Basically, I want to create a bar chart like that of example two in [jqplot examples](http://www.jqplot.com/examples/barTest.php). The code that generates the chart is:

```
    var s1 = [2, 6, 7, 10];
    var s2 = [7, 5, 3, 2];
    var ticks = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

    plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', [s1, s2], {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: { show: true }
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
            }
        }
    });
```

My chart will be based on a table. I want to replace the series array [S1,S2] with my own but failing so far. The problem is the outcome is one single array 1,2,3,4. Here is my code that does fetch data from column 1 of the table then from column 2. I want column1 to be s1 and column2 to be s2. However, based on needs, I might need more columns so I am interested in making it as dynamic as possible. The problem now is that I end up getting 1,2,3....all columns mixed. There is one more .each that gets which column t o index. It is working fine.

```
var chartData=[]; // to store S1,S2,S3 etc
var columnData=[]; //to store one set of array such as S1.
    $('#tblhighlight thead tr th.dbgroups ').each(function (index, groupname) {

            var valueColumn=index+2;    //which column to get data from

  $('#tblhighlight tbody tr td:nth-child('+valueColumn+') ').each(function (indexcell, cellvalue) {

columnData.push( parseInt($(cellvalue).html()));

            });

             chartData.push(columnData);

 });
```

I was hoping since columnData is an array, when pushed, it would be pushed as an array instead of individual items. How do I get past that please?

Comment: Not too sure if I completely follow your explanation nor what the exact problem is. But it does look suspicious that you keep storing data in `columnData` without ever clearing it. Before your inner loop, you should do `columnData=[]`, if I've understood what you're doing at all.

Comment: Basically, imagine i have the following records: S1= [1,2,3], S2=[1,2,3] which are dynamically generated and stored in columnData with .push method. Now i want to have a container array that will store them in this structure [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]. Pushing each group to the chartData gives me at last [1,2,3,4,5,6] which i dont want. Hope it makes sense.